# Email-Ext plugin templates not updated

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-email-ext

I'm working with jenkins pipeline. I'm using this plugin to send email notification  with the use templates. I reused an existing templates from github.

I place the templates `$Jenkins_Home\email-templates\`.

But my changes are not updated in the email. Still the old content was received.
Sample code:

```
def call(email, subject, content, attachment = null){   
def attachBuildLog = currentBuild.result != 'SUCCESS'
emailext attachLog: attachBuildLog,
         body: '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html"}',
         mimeType: 'text/html',
         subject: "${subject}",
         to: "${email}",
         replyTo: "${email}",
         recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: What if you would use a different name for the template? Is it an issue with overwriting a template or finding the template at all?

Comment: @hakamairi, I haven't tried that one. I'll come back and see if it works.

Comment: @hakamairi, after I changed the filename, it works. It was able to captured the changes I added to the template. With that, i think the problem is overwriting it.

Comment: glad it works for you ;)

Comment: anybody knows why this happens? after few updates to the template, I am always needed to rename the template file name and do corresponding changes at other places too :( 
Jenkins OS: ununtu16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the existing templates to a custom filename fixes the problem.

Comment: I cannot find the mail template file in the Jenkins home path , there is no mailtemplate folder in .jenkins and in the plugen mail ext folder where is this mmail template and after updating the ail template from the extension in manage jenkins still not updated I removed the mail template or add it with new name no change the mail always with the same template I have restarted jjenkins not resolved what I have to do